Hamiltonian Paths and Cycles in Graphs
Can someone verify if my proof is correct and rigorous? Thank you in advance!
Proposition: Let $G$ be a graph with at least 3 nodes such that every node has at least $n/2$ neighbors. If $G$ has a Hamiltonian path, then $G$ contains a Hamiltonian circuit.
I am attempting to prove this without using Dirac's or Ore's theorem.
Proof:
Assume $G$ contains a Hamiltonian path $P = v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_n$. By assumption, $v_0$ and $v_n$ each have at least $n/2$ neighbors. However, each can have at most $n-2$ possible neighbors excluding themselves and each other. Thus, considering both $v_0$ and $v_n$, we have $n/2 + n/2 = n$ potential connections, but only $n-2$ possible distinct neighbors. By the pigeonhole principle, there must be at least one vertex that is a common neighbor of both $v_0$ and $v_n$. Connecting $v_0$ and $v_n$ through this common neighbor forms a Hamiltonian circuit.

This doesn't work, because your "circuit" uses that common neighbour twice. A Hamilton circuit only has one more edge than a Hamilton path, but you are adding two edges without removing any.
Instead, look for a vertex $v_i$ such that $v_i$ is a neighbour of $v_0$ and $v_{i-1}$ is a neighbour of $v_n$. Now adding those two edges and removing $v_{i-1}v_i$ gives a Hamilton circuit.
